# .NET CORE - IE browser does not update method return

Tags: c#, .net-core

Consume an API method that returns a listing.

When calling this method a second time with the same parameters, the IE browser is not updating the return.

I tried to concatenate a random number in the URL, but still did not update on some clients.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo70L.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: since you're using a `GET` request the result is probably cached by IE